# get unique ajax value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a script that generates buttons with unique values through forich, such as price, etc., and when I click on the button, Ajax works for me, but data is transmitted only from the first button, how can I fix this? I don't really understand how to make it get the unique values of each button.

example foreach

```
    @foreach($examples as $example)
    @csrf
    <div class="new__content"> 
      <form style="background-color: #2A2929;" >
        <input type="hidden" value="{{$example->price}}" class="price">
        <input type="hidden" value="{{$example->name}}" class="name">
        <button class="buy-btn ajaxSubmit" onclick="event.preventDefault()">BUY</button>
      </form>
    </div> 
    @endforeach
```

example ajax

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('.ajaxSubmit').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajaxSetup({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
                }
            });
            jQuery.ajax({
                url: "{{ url('/buy') }}",
                method: 'get',
                data: {
                    price: jQuery('.name').val(),
                    gameid: jQuery('.gameid').val()
                },
                success: function(result){
                    console.log(result);
                }});
        });
    });
```

Comment: `$('.name').val()` will always get the value of the first, it's the same as `$('.name').first().val()` - do you want to send *all* the values of *all* the inputs at once?  Or just ones associated with each `.ajaxSubmit`, assuming there's more than one .ajaxSubmit? Note: `<input type='text'` is not a "button".

Comment: Here is the button -                 `<button class="buy-btn ajaxSubmit" onclick="event.preventDefault()">BUY</button>`

after foreach, I have 5-10 buttons generated, and I need that when clicking on each button, the values ​​of each of them go to Ajax, and not the first or all at once
--
Yes, only ones associated with each .ajaxSubmit

Comment: Please include how you generate the button/buttons in your question.   "5-10 buttons" overly vague.  Are these buttons relevant? Are they related to the inputs?  How are they related?  In a wrapper div?   Always directly after?  In a different div?  The html-relationship is relevant as you need to use DOM navigation to get from your button to the related inputs, eg `price: $(this).closest(".wrapper").find(".name").val()` where `this` will be the specific button that you click.

Comment: `@foreach($examples as $example)
@csrf
            <div class="new__content">
                <form style="background-color: #2A2929;" >
                    <input type="hidden" value="{{$example->price}}" class="price">
                    <input type="hidden" value="{{$example->name}}" class="name">
                <button class="buy-btn ajaxSubmit" onclick="event.preventDefault()">BUY</button>
            </form>
            </div>
        @endforeach`

Comment: Please [edit] your question, don't add blocks of code as comments.

Comment: Change your data:  `data: { price: $(this).closest("form").find(".price").val(), gameid: $(this).closest("form").find(".name").val() }`  (though price/name don't match your original name/gameid so just use the correct `value: ... .find(".value")...`